# Recorded audio using cordova media plugin not sounds like original

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I want to create a simple recording android application in meteor  and i am success in that using cordova media plugin but recorded sound is not like original sound .Please help me following is my code
**main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import  './main.html';
     window.onload = function()
                {
                    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
                }
           function onDeviceReady()
                {
                    document.getElementById("btnStart").addEventListener('click', startRecording, false);
                    document.getElementById("btnStop").addEventListener('click', stopRecording, false);
                    document.getElementById("playrecord").addEventListener('click', playRecording, false);
                    document.getElementById("pauserecord").addEventListener('click', pauseRecording, false);
                }
            var mymedia;
            function startRecording()
                {

                    var name = new Date().valueOf()
                    var src = "FinalAudio_"+name+".wav";
                    console.log("name"+name);
                    myMedia = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
                    myMedia.startRecord();
                    alert("Started recording");
                }
            function onSuccess() 
                {
                    console.log("Created Audio for Recording");
                }
            function onError(error) 
                {
                    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
                }
            function stopRecording()
                {
                    myMedia.stopRecord();
                    alert("Stopped recording");
                }
            function playRecording()
                {
                    myMedia.play();
                    myMedia.setVolume('1.0');
                }
            function pauseRecording()
                {
                    myMedia.pause();
                }
```

**main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>newapp</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> music}}

</body>

<template name="music">
  <input type="submit"   id="btnStart" value="Start Recording" class="btn btn-primary"><br><br>
  <input type="submit"  id="btnStop" value="Stop Recording" class="btn btn-primary"><br><br>
  <input type="submit"  id="playrecord" value="play Recording" class="btn btn-primary"><br><br>
  <input type="submit"  id="pauserecord" value="pause Recording" class="btn btn-primary"><br><br>
</template>
```

when i record sound and play it .its not sounds like original.please help me